# Quicksort algorithm with element in the middle as pivot

Tags: algorithm, pivot, quicksort

I had to do this little task where I had to sort an array 'by hand' like quicksort does. There is one specific point (the recursive one) where I am not sure if my solution is 
right. Would be nice if anyone could look through this!

Initial sequence: 7 4 6 8 9 1 3 2

Solution (i = left index, x = pivot, j = right index):
[Pivot-index = (i+j)/2]

```
Sort for positions 0 to 7:

i     x       j
7 4 6 8 9 1 3 2
(swap 8 and 2)

      i       j
7 4 6 8 9 1 3 2

        i   j
7 4 6 2 9 1 3 8
(swap 9 and 3)

          i
          j
7 4 6 2 3 1 9 8

Sort for positions 0 to 5:
i   x     j
7 4 6 2 3 1 9 8
(swap 7 and 1)

  i     j
1 4 6 2 3 7 9 8
(swap 6 and 3)

      i
      j
1 4 3 2 6 7 9 8

Sort for positions 0 to 3:
i x   j
1 4 3 2 6 7 9 8
(swap 4 and 2)

    i
    j
1 2 3 4 6 7 9 8

Sort for positions 0 to 2:
i x j
1 2 3 4 6 7 9 8
(swap 2 'and' 2)

j   i
1 2 3 4 6 7 9 8

Sort for positions 6 to 7 (from first split - not sure here!)

            i j
            x
1 2 3 4 6 7 9 8
(swap 9 and 8)

            j i
1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9
```

Used code:

```
public class QuickSort {
  public static void sort (int[] a) {       // public method
    quicksort(a, 0, a.length-1);            // starts private method
  }
  private static void quicksort (int[] a, int left, int right) {
    int tmp;                                // temporary param
    int i = left;                           // left index
    int j = right;                          // right index
    int middle = (left + right) / 2;        // middle position
    int x = a[middle];                      // pivot element
    do {
      while (a[i] < x) i++;                 // x works as break
      while (a[j] > x) j--;                 // x works as break
        if (i <= j) {
          tmp = a[i];                       // temporary storage
          a[i] = a[j];                      // a[i] and
          a[j] = tmp;                       // a[j] get swapped
          i++;
          j--;
        }
    } while (i <= j);
                                            // all elements on the left side of the array are smaller than
                                            // all elements in the right side of the array
    if (left < j) quicksort(a, left, j);    // sort left side
    if (i < right) quicksort(a, i, right);  // sort right side
  }
}
```

Comment: This site isn't really intended for having people check your homework.

Comment: Where is the problem? Did it myself and just wanted to seek help?! Where is this site instead intended for? Professionals chatting with professionals about professional stuff? If so, sorry for asking!

Comment: where is the code, and why cant qsort or std::sort do it?

Comment: Don't worry sizzle, I didn't flag you or anything.  I just wanted to give you a heads up that you might receive some pushback on this question, as it is a little unconventional for this site.  With few exceptions, well received questions on this site are supposed to be specific questions about specific code with definitive answers.

Comment: Ok, than I got to say sorry for this pretty unspecific question! I now attached the Java code used for the algorithm. I hope my future questions will be more challenging for you and that I can contribute something as well when my skills have somewhat more progressed! ;)
@sp2danny We had to do this by hand.

Comment: Althought,it's no harm in posting this here but @sizzle why don't you post your question to codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Because I didn't know of that section. But thanks for the hint!

Comment: that algorithm works like a charm. what are you unsure about more precisely?

Comment: Yes, the algorithm works perfectly. But I tried to do the sorting by hand (like the algorithm does) and was not sure about the step where the sorting of the arrays right side starts. I have marked this concern also in my solution "log" inside brackets.